# MYSQL select recent record of each from

Tags: php, mysql, sql

See my table(sample_table),

```
----------------------------- 
id    |   from    |    to   |
----------------------------- 
1     |    2      |    1    |
3     |    2      |    1    |
4     |    2      |    4    |
5     |    3      |    2    |
9     |    3      |    1    |
11    |    4      |    1    |
12    |    4      |    3    |
-----------------------------
```

For each `from`, I would like the row holding the most recent `to`, where `to` = 1

I mean I want only following,

```
----------------------------- 
id    |   from    |    to   |
----------------------------- 
3     |    2      |    1    |
9     |    3      |    1    |
11    |    4      |    1    |
-----------------------------
```

I Try following Query,

```
SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE to = 1 GROUP BY from
```

It's giving first row of each. Help me.

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it and here is one way

```
select t1.* from sample_table t1
join(
  select max(id) as id,`from` from 
  sample_table where `to` = 1 
  group by `from`
)t2
on t1.id= t2.id and t1.`from` = t2.`from`
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select t1.id, t1.from, t1.to from table as t1 inner join
(
select to, from,min(id) as id from table 
where to=1 
group by to,from
) as t2 
on t1.to=t2.to and t1.id=2.id and t1.from=t2.from
```